# C++ basic pointer question

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, lifetime, destruction

I have some shared pointer `shared_ptr<T> pointer1(new T(1));`.

Now, in some other part of code I have an explicit copy of `pointer2` (guess it would be stored in a `std::map` or some other container). Let's say that copy was done like `map.insert(make_pair(key1, pointer1));`.

I am using that second copy only to precache some data and this means that if the main pointer *is already invalid*, there is no need to store the second pointer. **What should I do in this case?**

Is there any way to force the memory deallocation for the second pointer if I know that `pointer1` became invalid in some other part of my code?

Or should I take the ugly way - from time to time check my map for pointers which have `ptr.unique()` set to `true` and destruct them?

*Maybe some alternatives / advices?*

---

### Edit - plain code sample

```
std::map<int, shared_ptr<int> > map;

{
   shared_ptr<int> pointer1(new int(5));
   map.insert(std::make_pair(0, pointer1));
}
```

*Is there any way / trick to make map contain `<0, shared_ptr[NULL]>` instead of `<0, shared_ptr[5]>` after these operations happen?*

Thanks

Comment: Write code rather than English. English is not very precise and type information and code are always key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is a task for weak_ptr:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm

Try putting them in your table instead of a shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using that second copy only to precache some data and this means that if the main pointer is already invalid, there is no need to store the second pointer. What should I do in this case?

You should look at boost::weak_ptr
If the associated shared_ptr has been reset then the weak_ptr knows about it.

> Is there any way to force the memory deallocation for the second pointer if I know that pointer1 became invalid in some other part of my code?

Don't think so.
But if you use weak pointer this will not be required.